# Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle' - A consumer group is required for a partitioned subscription

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm having a problem on test a Spring Cloud Stream 3.1.3 application.
I've this `application.yml`:

```
...
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input-in-0:
          destination: {DESTINATION}
          contentType: application/json
          group: {GROUP}
...
```

Obviously I wrote a Consumer method annotated with `@Bean` that I named `input();`

I replaced, for tests, this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

with this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
</dependency>
```

And finally this is the test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    private Application application;

    @Test
    void shouldStartTheApplication(){
        Assertions.assertNotNull(application);
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this test with new `test-binder` dependency, test fails and logs this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A consumer group is required for a partitioned subscription
```

Instead, if I don't replace `spring-cloud-stream-test-support`, test passes.

Why, according dependencies I use, is test result different?
Thank you

Comment: I have very similar binding configuration as yours running with `test-binder` and `spring-cloud-stream` 3.1.3, everything works fine for me. What yours `application.yaml` is not showing, is that the consumer is running in partitioned mode, that's what the error message says. So somewhere `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.partitioned: true` is set (maybe `test.yaml` is overwriting you application.yaml?). I can reproduce the error message if I set `group: ""`.  Why it's working with `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` is a good question. Could you provide minimalistic FULL sample?